# LiveCharts set DateTime X-Axis MinValue and MaxValue in order to zoom in/out

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datetimepicker, livecharts

I have a `WPF` application using `LiveCharts` where I plot a `LineGraph` with X-Axis being `DateTime`. My end goal here is to achieve a 'two-way' zoom. That is, I have two `DateTimePicker` controls (from [WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker)) on my application that represent the minimum and maximum `DateTime` of the *currently displayed area* of the graph, and if I use scroll wheel on the graph area to zoom in/out, the updated range should be reflected on the said controls, and (this is the part I'm struggling with) conversely, if I set min/max on the `DateTimePicker` controls, the graph should zoom in/out accordingly.

My `XAML` is pretty simple:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <lvc:CartesianChart Name="MyChart"
                        Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}"
                        Zoom="X">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}"
                      PreviewRangeChangedCommand="{Binding XRangeChangedCommand}"
                      MinValue="{Binding TimeStampMin, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      MaxValue="{Binding TimeStampMax, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <xceed:DateTimePicker Margin="4" Width="160" Name="dtpMinX"
                              Format="Custom" FormatString="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
                              Value="{Binding TimeStampMin, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <xceed:DateTimePicker Margin="4" Width="160" Name="dtpMaxX"
                              Format="Custom" FormatString="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
                              Value="{Binding TimeStampMax, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here's my `DataPoint` class:

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public DataPoint() { }

    public DataPoint(DateTime timeStamp, double value)
    {
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        Value = value;
    }

    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my `PlotGraph()` method that does all the plotting work. I'll include my entire `MainWindow()` code at the bottom of this post if you want to reproduce this application.

```
private void PlotGraph()
{
    var mapper = Mappers.Xy<DataPoint>()
        .X(dp => dp.TimeStamp.Ticks)
        .Y(dp => dp.Value);
    SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection(mapper);

    var lineSeries = new LineSeries
    {
        Values = DataPoints.AsChartValues(),
        Fill = Brushes.Transparent
    };
    SeriesCollection.Add(lineSeries);

    TimeStampMin = DataPoints.FirstOrDefault().TimeStamp;
    TimeStampMax = DataPoints.LastOrDefault().TimeStamp;

    Formatter = value => new DateTime((long)value).ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");

    DataContext = this;
}
```

Now when I run this and zoom in/out using mouse, the updated end value of my time stamps will be reflected on the `DateTimePicker` controls just fine. However if I try to set the value in the `DateTimePicker` controls in order to zoom in/out, it won't co-operate. When I try, in my `Output` window, I get the following two binding related error messages:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
>   not valid for target property.; Value='10/09/2019 15:50:41'
>   BindingExpression:Path=TimeStampMin; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name='');
>   target element is 'Axis' (Name=''); target property is 'MinValue'
>   (type 'Double')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by
>   BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='10/09/2019
>   16:00:54' BindingExpression:Path=TimeStampMax; DataItem='MainWindow'
>   (Name=''); target element is 'Axis' (Name=''); target property is
>   'MaxValue' (type 'Double')

This tells me that the problem is in binding, that `Axis.MinValue` and `Axis.MaxValue` are expecting a double whereas my `TimeStampMin` and `TimeStampMax` are, obviously, `DateTime` objects. How would I do the conversion so that I can achieve the two-way zoom?

---

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YWtp37) is my entire `MainWindow` code if you want to reproduce it. I'm using `MVVMLight` toolkit for commands etc., so you might have to get the `NuGet` package if you want to run this as is.

Looks like some people can't access the link so here's the full code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Func<double, string> Formatter
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private DateTime _timeStampMin;
    public DateTime TimeStampMin
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeStampMin;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_timeStampMin == value)
                return;
            _timeStampMin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TimeStampMin");
        }
    }

    private DateTime _timeStampMax;
    public DateTime TimeStampMax
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeStampMax;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_timeStampMax == value)
                return;
            _timeStampMax = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TimeStampMax");
        }
    }

    public List<DataPoint> DataPoints
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RelayCommand<PreviewRangeChangedEventArgs> XRangeChangedCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        XRangeChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<PreviewRangeChangedEventArgs>(e => XRangeChanged(e));
        InitializeData();
        PlotGraph();
    }

    private void InitializeData()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        DataPoints = new List<DataPoint>{new DataPoint()
        {Value = 1, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(1)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 4, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(2)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 9, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(3)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 16, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(4)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 25, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(5)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 36, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(6)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 49, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(7)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 64, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(8)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 81, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(9)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 100, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(10)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 11 * 11, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(11)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 12 * 12, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(12)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 13 * 13, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(13)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 14 * 14, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(14)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 15 * 15, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(15)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 16 * 16, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(16)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 17 * 17, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(17)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 18 * 18, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(18)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 19 * 19, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(19)}, new DataPoint()
        {Value = 20 * 20, TimeStamp = now.AddMinutes(20)}, };
    }

    private void PlotGraph()
    {
        var mapper = Mappers.Xy<DataPoint>().X(dp => dp.TimeStamp.Ticks).Y(dp => dp.Value);
        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection(mapper);
        var lineSeries = new LineSeries{Values = DataPoints.AsChartValues(), Fill = Brushes.Transparent};
        SeriesCollection.Add(lineSeries);
        TimeStampMin = DataPoints.FirstOrDefault().TimeStamp;
        TimeStampMax = DataPoints.LastOrDefault().TimeStamp;
        Formatter = value => new DateTime((long)value).ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public void XRangeChanged(PreviewRangeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeStampMin = DateTime.FromBinary((long)e.PreviewMinValue);
        TimeStampMax = DateTime.FromBinary((long)e.PreviewMaxValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: your link to download your solution is bugged

Comment: @Frenchy added the code to the post.

Comment: Could you show your class relaycommand...?

Comment: @Frenchy it's a part of the `MVVMLight` toolkit. If you install it via nuget you can simply use the command. http://www.mvvmlight.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you had a part of answer when you said the problem was between double and datetime for Min and Max value for Axis X:

You have two solutions: either using Converter, either separate the value between datepicker and min/max value: here the second solution:

in xaml file:

```
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}"
                  PreviewRangeChangedCommand="{Binding XRangeChangedCommand}"
                  MinValue="{Binding TimeStampMinX, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  MaxValue="{Binding TimeStampMaxX, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
```

in cs.file:

```
    private double _timeStampMinX;
    public double TimeStampMinX
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeStampMinX;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_timeStampMinX == value)
                return;
            _timeStampMinX = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TimeStampMinX");
        }
    }

    private double _timeStampMaxX;
    public double TimeStampMaxX
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeStampMaxX;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_timeStampMaxX == value)
                return;
            _timeStampMaxX = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TimeStampMaxX");
        }
    }
    private DateTime _timeStampMin;
    public DateTime TimeStampMin
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeStampMin;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_timeStampMin == value)
                return;
            _timeStampMin = value;
            TimeStampMinX = value.Ticks;
            OnPropertyChanged("TimeStampMin");
        }
    }

    private DateTime _timeStampMax;
    public DateTime TimeStampMax
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeStampMax;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_timeStampMax == value)
                return;
            _timeStampMax = value;
            TimeStampMaxX = value.Ticks;
            OnPropertyChanged("TimeStampMax");
        }
    }
```

the link between DateTime and double value is the DateTime.Ticks.

---

the solution with a converter:

The class converter:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((DateTime)value).Ticks;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

the integration of converter in xaml file (change the namespace WpfApp2 with your namespace)

```
    xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <dc:DateTimeConverter x:Key="DateTimeConverter"></dc:DateTimeConverter>
</Window.Resources>
                        :
                        :
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}"
                  PreviewRangeChangedCommand="{Binding XRangeChangedCommand}"
                  MinValue="{Binding TimeStampMin, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}"
                  MaxValue="{Binding TimeStampMax, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}"/>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
```

in this case no need to separate the binding value, the converter does the job.

Comment: The second approach is clean and concise. I really like it, thanks!